# maven archetype:generate failure caused by org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException

Tags: maven, ubuntu, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3

I have installed maven 2 and following the tutorial as mentioned in the below link

maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

But while executing the archetype:generate command,

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false"
```

I am getting the below error

```
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Error merging velocity templates
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Error merging velocity templates
at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:211)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
... 17 more
```

For information,

I am using Sun OpenJDK 1.6.0, Maven 2 and Xubuntu platform.

Any suggestive help on the above error will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Somnath

Answer (score 8):

It looks like there is a problem with folder access.. Check if the folder where your are trying to create a project is write protected? If it is so, then change its permission to 777 and check if it works.

Comment: Actually I was trying to integrate the maven plug-in for eclipse so that I can build the hadoop-common-project (SVN link is http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/) using the pom.xml packages that it comes with. As I understand, I am just trying to create an artifactId = /my-app and groupId = com.mycompany.app from some archetype-generic Ids. It will create the folder with some default access control. I don't have root-access but the username I am using has the admin profile. I mean I can run sudo command.

Comment: @somnathchakrabarti Did it work? Coz  you are using mvn archetype:generate which is going to create a project and going to create corresponding group id related folders in the maven local repo. So make sure access for both the locations is available for the user.

Answer (score 2):

I had also faced the same issue, still I had all the required permissions to create the folder and files. But it turned out that there was an error in archetype.xml - I was trying add a folder without any files in it -

```
 <testResources>
   <resource>src/test/resources/</resource>
 </testResources>
```

After correcting archetype.xml, I got the build succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its definitely the permission error. Spent 2 days on it and simply rectified it using sudo :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error :D, and what I did was modifying the permission of the folder in which I was creating my project folder (in you case 'my-app'). Indeed, I was just following the maven tutorial's guidelines when I came into this error.

Changing '/usr/local/apache-maven/' folder permission to 775 or to 777 should make it!

Answer (score 0):

**If you encounter this error while using an IDE (such as Eclipse) then close and reopen the IDE and try again.**

I received this error (`Error merging velocity templates`) on Windows 10 using Eclipse after creating then deleting a project  into the target folder, then creating my Maven project into the target folder. First, I tried relaxing security on the folder via my Admin account -- but, I was denied access! Finally, after closing Eclipse I saw the folder vanish in Windows Explorer.

I assume that my IDE was exclusively holding the handle for the folder, so it is generally worth noting on Windows that you may have to close other programs (or restart) to fix this issue.