# Hadoop MapReduce Job Input File ClassNotFound

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am building a sample Map/Reduce task on a hadoop cluster comprising two nodes - master/slave and slave. 
Following are my specs:

```
$HADOOP_HOME = /usr/local/hadoop
My M/R classfiles path = $HADOOP_HOME/MyMapRed_classes
My Mapper classfile = $HADOOP_HOME/MyMapRed_classes/MyMapper
My Reducer classfile = $HADOOP_HOME/MyMapRed_classes/MyReducer
My Jar path = $HADOOP_HOME/MyMapred/MyMapRed.jar
My HDFS Input Path = /user/hadoop/MyMapRed/inputfile
My HDFS Output Path = /user/hadoop/MyMapRed_output
```

I am running the M/R task as follows

```
<myusername>@localhost:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/MyMapRed/MyMapRed.jar -input /user/hadoop/MyMapRed/inputfile -output /user/hadoop/MyMapRed_output/ -mapper $HADOOP_HOME/MyMapRed_classes/MyMapper -reducer $HADOOP_HOME/MyMapRed_classes/MyReducer
```

But it seems it is not being able to find the input file as evident from below message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -input
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

Below is the MyMapRed class that I am using. It has as input a list of  pairs. The reducer is supposed to give the average Val per group.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;


public class MyMapRed {

public static class MyMapper extends MapReduceBase 
implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {

    private final static Text Group = new Text();
    private final static DoubleWritable Val = new DoubleWritable();

    public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter) 
        throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] KeyAndVal = line.split("\t",2);
        Group.set(KeyAndVal[0]);
        Val.set(Double.valueOf(KeyAndVal[1]));
        output.collect(Group, Val);
    }
}

public static class MyReducer extends MapReduceBase 
implements Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, DoubleWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<DoubleWritable> values,
            OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        DoubleWritable val = new DoubleWritable();
        double valSum = 0.0;
        int valCnt = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            val = values.next();
            valSum += val.get();
            valCnt++;
        }
        if (valCnt>0)
            valSum = valSum/valCnt;
        output.collect(key, new DoubleWritable(valSum));
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JobClient client = new JobClient();
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(MyMapRed.class);
    conf.setJobName("MyMapRed");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path("input"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("output"));

    client.setConf(conf);

    try {
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Can anybody suggest what I am missing out for ClassNotFoundException to be raised ?

Comment: Is your mapper and reducer written in Java code? If so why are you trying to use streaming?.

Comment: Yes, I am using Java. Currently I am using Eclipse 3.5.2 (Galileo) and I don't see any way to run a MR job on Hadoop from Eclipse. I did try to integrate Maven to build the hadoop-common-project (SVN link: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/) and thereby to run any MR job from Eclipse but the build was failure which I posted in the other thread link yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164370/maven-archetypegenerate-failure-caused-by-org-apache-maven-plugin-mojofailureex. To check, I am using streaming to see if the M/R is actually working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your MapRed.jar file doesn't have a main class defined in the jars manifest, then hadoop expects the argument after the jar to be a class containing the static main method.

You'll need to name your main class (the one that contains the `public static void main(String args[])` method and configures a job via the JobConf or Job class).

If also looks like you're trying to use streaming, which isn't necessary if your mapper and reducer is written in Java

Comment: Is there a way that I can configure the Runtime Environment to run on Hadoop? I did some research yesterday and came to know that the hadoop-${version}-eclipse-plugin.jar is needed under ${eclipse.home}/plugins/ directory for creating MR project in eclipse. The ${eclipse.home} is typically /usr/lib/eclipse/ and this path is added as entry eclipse.home = /usr/lib/eclipse/ in $HADOOP_HOME/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/build.properties for Hadoop to recognize eclipse home while building/compiling any MR job. So, it's like a 2-way process

Comment: I am not very sure about what is the difference between Streaming and normal Map/Reduce. In addition to my above comment, can you pls elaborate a little?

Comment: I have added the details of Mapper/Reducer class with the JobConf details.