# Maven creating quickstart template

Tags: java, maven

I am learning maven. I just installed maven.

```
mvn -version
```

says

```
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T23:07:52+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Users\gopir\Documents\MyJabberFiles\mohanasw@netapp.com\apache-maven-3.2.1-bin\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I tried to create a project with the help of

```
 mvn -e archetype:generate -DgroupId=x:y -DartifactId=testMaven -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I am getting the following error

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-\     
 plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error merging 
 velocity templates -> [Help 1]
 he.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal 
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) 
 on project standalone-pom: Error merging velocity templa...
```

Is it default one? What should i change to get my pom.xml and other directories?

Thanks

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164370/maven-archetypegenerate-failure-caused-by-org-apache-maven-plugin-mojofailureex

Comment: @RC. Project structure created `/src/main/java and pom.xml` but error exists. That link didn't help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will list here the steps that I use on a regular basis(as of today).
You can compare your steps and see where you need change. The relative paths are shown for Mac / OSX. Which isn't different, conceptually, than windows.

> All of the commands in the following are to be run on terminal.
>
> 1. `cd` into workspace or `mkdir` for project folder
>      /Users/ProjectFolder
> 2. run the following command `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.folder.name.you.like -DartifactId=NameOfProject -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`
> 3. cd into the folder named as artifactID and run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
> 4. File->import->Select Existing Project Into Workspace  the project in eclipse as existing project and give the path to the artifactId
>      from above. Check to make sure you have the pom.xml in the eclipse project once the import succeeds.
> 5. Add the following plugin for maven compiler in pom.xml (this is for
>      java 1.8)

```
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

> 6. Add source files to the project in eclipse 
>      run the following command from the same present directory (as in #3
>      above) `mvn package`

Comment: Thanks. Succeeded. I have few doubts. Will you please clear those? What is maven-compiler-plugin version? Is it related to maven version? I didn't see my class files after executing `mvn package` under `target` directory. plus1

Comment: I can see the class files in my directory but not under my eclipse target. I tried `maven-> update project` in eclipse

Comment: You can add the following line within your <build> tag in pom.xml to always see the .class for all of your .java `<build>
    <outputDirectory>bin/classes</outputDirectory>
...` maven-compiler-plugin version is the version of maven  that is installed on the machine. For the .class It is same way for me, I can see the .class in my directory but not in my eclise project but as above I always include the line to show the .class

Answer (score 3):

To create a maven quick start project use the following command.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.testpackage
   -DartifactId=DemoProject
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
   -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Refer: [How to create a Java Project with Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/)

Comment: It was a typo. Same as yours

Comment: No, I am referring the same site.

Comment: Okay, have you tried with this command first `mvn archetype:generate`. Here it will give several options of all the project list. From which we can select one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try and let you know

Comment: @GopsAB Try with above edited answer. I have tried and success in build.

Comment: Yes, Succeeded. I have added few doubts below answers. can you please explain those? And same command i executed yesterday. it wasn't working. But now it's working. Is there anything with net connections? Because i am using better net connection than yesterday. +1

Comment: 1. `maven-compiler-plugin` is name of `artifactId` based on which the jar can be created and  2. we can release multiple jars with same artifactId (means name of the jar we can say) and it will be differentiated by version number.

Answer (score 0):

Something else that could help you. If you type **mvn archetype:generate** on the command line it will enter in an interactive mode and will list a big bunch of maven archetypes for you (I see more than 1300 templates in my cmd) and will prompt you to enter the number of one of them. Them it will lead you step by step (in an interactive fashion) into creating your project on the basis of the chosen template.

[image: list of archetypes]